# Bitcoin core delay in synching

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

My bitcoin core is delaying in sync saying two years remaining. And av sent bitcoin from my block chain wallet it's been deducted but am not seeing it. How can I go about it seeing that I can't wait for two years. The synching is not fast

Answer (score 1):

The "two years behind" is not telling you how long the synchronization will take but what time you are caught up with. Bitcoin processes history much faster than real time.  If you are at two years behind you are most of the way done.  If you click the "behind" text it should give you an estimated time left counter.

Syncing speed depends on your hardware. The first time takes anywhere from a day (on reasonably fast hardware) to a few days (on slower hardware).  After that it doesn't take long on restart.